# Save event type logs

Tags: android, json, sqlite, logging, android-sqlite

We want to add a reporting feature to our existing application.
For this purpose we are sending Events in `JSON` via `HTTPS` to a server application.

We need to remember Event-objects that could not be send to the server (No internet, server not reachable...). We are considering to store the events in a `SQLite` database and discard all Events that are older than 24 hours to prevent flooding our storage.

Another option would be to write the JSON-objects to a file and concat each new event when it could not be send to the server. The problem with this solution is, that it would be hard for us to discard logs older than 24 hours.

We store the event sin a table with the columns:

| id | json | created_at |

Can anyone recommend best practices for this use case?

Currently we tend to use the `sqlite` solution but we are wondering if there are any caveats that we are not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using third-party lib i can recommend [android-priority-jobqueue](https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue). You can easily achieve what you are trying to do. You can always create job and it will handle itself. You can set if it needs network, if it is persistent (saved into DB when no network) and even you can customize your own retry logic.

Here's little example.

```
public class PostTweetJob extends Job {
    public static final int PRIORITY = 1;
    private String text;
    public PostTweetJob(String text) {
        // This job requires network connectivity,
        // and should be persisted in case the application exits before job is completed.
        super(new Params(PRIORITY).requireNetwork().persist());
    }
    @Override
    public void onAdded() {
        // Job has been saved to disk.
        // This is a good place to dispatch a UI event to indicate the job will eventually run.
    }
    @Override
    public void onRun() throws Throwable {
        // yours code here
    }
    @Override
    protected RetryConstraint shouldReRunOnThrowable(Throwable throwable, int runCount,
            int maxRunCount) {
        // An error occurred in onRun.
        return RetryConstraint.createExponentialBackoff(runCount, 1000);
    }
}
```

And you call it like this.

```
jobManager.addJobInBackground(new PostTweetJob("It works"));
```

Comment: will this handle many jobs well?
Our app can produce up to ten thousand events per day.

Comment: I think so. It is using SQLite internaly so i think it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

use JobService(Android 5+ - lollipop and above) and AlarmManager (for android sdk<21 - pre lollipop) with this solution u can schedule any task and it would be performed. JobService was developed rxactely for tjis purposes(schedule and perform different tasks) maybe you can try JobIntentService it is would work on kitkat(android 4+) devices

P.S.
In that case you didnt need any third party libs and other dependrncies like firebase/google play services(like for FirebaseDispatcher)